# How to postpone rendering of Raster in Paperjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, paperjs

In this example:
http://jsbin.com/uPECeKUP/1/

In Paperjs [Raster](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/) is being rendered immediately after creation. is there way to postpone rendering, perform some operations on raster (scaling, repositioning, filtering), and then put in on the canvas?

ps
Does canvas fire any events on rendering?

Answer (score 0):

The canvas is altered by a draw routine, which I believe is only called if the view itself has changed. Therefore you can do your processing out of the view's bounds, on another canvas, or on an object whose visibility is 'false':

```
myPaper = new paper.PaperScope();

myPaper.setup($("#c")[0]);

var raster = new myPaper.Raster({
  source:'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KPnRx1slIH0/UMs_0gCpVnI/AAAAAAAADHM/i6ATMHNI_rI/s320/National+Geographic+HD+Wallpapers+26.jpg',
  position: {x:100, y:100},
  visible: false
})

raster.onLoad = function () {
    raster.rotate(35);
    raster.visible = true;
}
```

AFAIK, canvas does not fire an event upon rendering.